# what R function fits a smoothing spline regression model with correlated errors?

Tags: regression, autoregressive, splines

I want to fit a smoothing spline regression model with correlated errors (it's a time series) using R.  All I could find is function `ssr`, from library `assist`, which is not on CRAN [anymore](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assist/index.html) -- I am pretty lukewarm about installing a package from source when it does not appear it's maintained.  So I am looking for an alternative, and I would be obliged for any suggestion.

BTW, my model is meant to look like something like

```
raw_measurement = parameter_estimate + {time of day spilne} + {other splines} + {AR(1) distributed error}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a pity that `assist` is no longer maintained, I used that package myself.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to cajole your problem to fit into `gam` routines provided in package `mcgv`, because one of the smoothers is for Markov Random Fields (MRF).  Although it appears that it is designed for geographical regions, your error still have markov structure with an AR(1) process.  Try

```
library(mcgv)
?mrf
```

and see if that might not work for you.